# Display multiple google chart regions in the same map

Tags: google-visualization

I am creating a Google Geo Chart that includes cities in the US, South Korea, Taiwan, China, and India. If I use `regions: 'world'` tshe map will be too big and the city bubbles will be barely visible. I am using the following options:

```
var options = {
  region: 'world',
  displayMode: 'markers',
  resolution: 'provinces'
}
```

**Would it be possible to create a map with two or more regions?**

For example, US and Asia. I am thinking about setting the regions using something like the following:

```
var options = {
  region: '019','142',
  displayMode: 'markers',
  resolution: 'provinces'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to create a map of two regions on the same map.

The reason is that Google geocharts rely on SVG images of whatever region they are showing, and there are a limited amount of SVG maps that exist within the API (this is why some countries do not work with `resolution: 'provinces'`).

However, it is possible to create a datatable with data for both regions, and use the same datatable to populate two separate maps (one of each area).

For instance:

```
<!--
You are free to copy and use this sample in accordance with the terms of the
Apache license (http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html)
-->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Google Visualization API Sample</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['geochart']});

      function drawVisualization() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Country', 'Popularity'],
          ['Germany', 200],
          ['United States', 300],
          ['Brazil', 400],
          ['Canada', 500],
          ['France', 600],
          ['RU', 700]
        ]);

        // Draw First Chart
        var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(
          document.getElementById('visualization'));
        geochart.draw(data, {width: 556, height: 347, region: '019', resolution: 'countries'});

        // Draw Second Chart
        var geochart2 = new google.visualization.GeoChart(
          document.getElementById('visualization2'));
        geochart2.draw(data, {width: 556, height: 347, region: '150', resolution: 'countries'});
      }


      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <div id="visualization"></div>
    <div id="visualization2"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also note that the "Americas" region (019) is as tall as the world map, and won't actually save you any space over "world". I would suggest using North America or just 'US' if there aren't any markers in Canada or Mexico.